# how do i request the types and number of surface children in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, children, surface

```
import pygame as pg # rename pygame module with pg
import sys # application termination for some windows machines

def main():
    pg.init() #initialize pygame
    clock = pg.time.Clock() #create a time object
    fps = 30 #game frame rate
    size = [400, 400] #screen size
    bg = [255, 255, 255] #screen background

    screen = pg.display.set_mode(size)
    surface = pg.Surface(screen.get_size())

    blocks = []
    block_color = [255, 0, 0]

    def create_blocks(blocks):
        """ function will create blocks and assign a position to them"""

        block_width = 20
        block_height = 20

        # nested for loop for fast position assignment
        for i in range(0, 40, block_width):
            for j in range(0, 40, block_height):
                # offsets block objects 20px from one another
                x = 2*i
                y = 2*j

                #block rect object
                rect = pg.Rect(x, y, block_width, block_height)

                #append rect to blocks list
                blocks.append(rect)

    def draw_blocks(surface, blocks, block_color):
        """ draws blocks object to surface"""

        #loops through rects in the blocks list and draws them on surface
        for block in blocks:
            pg.draw.rect(surface, block_color, block)

    create_blocks(blocks)

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return False

        screen.blit(surface, [0, 0])
        surface.fill(bg)

        draw_blocks(surface, blocks, block_color)

        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

    pg.quit() # closses pygame window
    sys.exit # for machines that wont accept pygame quit() event

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a test code i made to visualize my question. What i'm asking is basically a method by which i can somehow request the types and number of children inside my surface object.  For example if i had a circle, a square, a line or other type of object within my surface i want a list of all the types that are in my surface and i also want the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surfaces only hold information about the pixels/colors they consist of, not about the shapes that you draw on them. If you want to know how many shapes there are, you have to use lists, `pygame.sprite.Group`s or other data structures to store information about them.

You already have the blocks (which are `pygame.Rect`s) in your `blocks` list, so you just need to call `len(blocks)` to get the number of blocks. You can as well use rects to store circles in a `circles` list.

Eventually you could create your own `Shape` classes or use `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s and put instances of them into your lists/sprite groups.